# MS Access monthly average for two criteria

Tags: ms-access, average

Still new to using Access. I searched, but could only find averages for 1 criteria, like Car average. I am trying to get monthly averages for an item with two options. Here is my example data

[image]

Here is the output I am trying to go for. It is the average for each Item for X and Z for the month of data.
[image]

Here is what I have, but I'm getting "Syntax error FROM clause". I used similar information that I received from a previous request so I may be way off base on how to get this information.

```
Select Item, [X or Z], Date, Value FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Item, Date, AVG(Value) As Average FROM Mytable
GROUP BY Item, [X or Z]
AS t ON (t.[X or Z] = [X or Z])
AND (t.Item = Item)
AND (t.Average = Value)
```

I have been doing this in SQL view, but would this be something I could achieve in Design view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single query, without joins:

```
SELECT Item, [X or Z], Format([Date], "MMMM") As Month, Avg(Value) As AvgOfValue
From MyTable
GROUP BY Item, [X or Z], Format([Date], "MMMM")
```

This query can be represented in design view.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.